# Noun phrase / verb agreement in number

Tags: grammar

Which form of *be* is correct:

> Very small amounts of salt that [is/are] present in commercial fish foods also help aquatic species remain in balance.

Comment: The question was clear enough to me. I've edited it for clarity, however. The edit is pending review.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Number agreement between subject and object](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17212/number-agreement-between-subject-and-object)

Comment: @RoaringFish Not really, because the issue here is whether the relative clause is modifying *various amounts of salt* or just *salt*! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Are* is correct because *amounts* is plural:

> Very small amounts of salt that *are* present...

*Amount* is usually uncountable, which may be one reason behind the need to ask the question. But it is sometimes countable, and it is a countable noun in this context.

You can also leave out [that are]. The following is grammatically standard:

> Very small amounts of salt present in commercial fish foods also help aquatic species remain in balance.

Comment: Right answer for the wrong reason. It is *are* because *amounts* is plural, not because it is countable. It could be phrased as "The very small amount of salt that *is* present..."

Comment: I've modified the explanation. Thanks. I suspect that some people might not know that amount is sometimes countable, and therefore capable of being plural.